# In Framer motion animate divs, on hover stop animating

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I got four divs that goes from left: 100% to left: 0. When i hover one of them, it stops animation. And when i unhover i wanna to keep going to left:0 and then after animation is over repeat that from position left:100%. But problem is that when animation is over it starts from position where i hover last.

```
"use client";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";

const divsData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    initialX: "100%",
    hoverScale: 1.2,
    color: "bg-blue-500",
    delay: -2.5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    initialX: "100%",
    hoverScale: 1.2,
    color: "bg-green-500",
    delay: -7,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    initialX: "100%",
    hoverScale: 1.2,
    color: "bg-yellow-500",
    delay: -12.5,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    initialX: "100%",
    hoverScale: 1.2,
    color: "bg-purple-500",
    delay: -17,
  },
];

const CardJob = () => {
  const controls = useAnimation();

  const handleHoverStart = () => {
    controls.stop();
  };

  const handleHoverEnd = () => {
    controls.start(
      { left: 0 },
      {
        autoplay: true,
        repeat: Infinity,
        duration: 3,
        ease: "linear",
        repeatType: "loop",
      }
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleHoverEnd();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {divsData.map((divData) => (
        <motion.div
          key={divData.id}
          initial={{ y: divData.id * 50, left: "100%" }}
          animate={controls}
          onMouseEnter={handleHoverStart}
          onMouseLeave={handleHoverEnd}
          className={`absolute w-10 h-10 ${divData.color}`}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default CardJob;
```